# Cannot find module 'extend' Lambda node JS in AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, request

I want my lambda to make a POST request with the request lib. 
I only try to define a variable request based on the lib I installed with npm :

```
var request = require('request');
```

I get this error:

```
  {
      "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'extend'",
      "errorType": "Error",
      "stackTrace": [
        "Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)",
        "Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)",
        "Module.require (module.js:364:17)",
        "require (module.js:380:17)",
        "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/request/index.js:17:29)",
        "Module._compile (module.js:456:26)",
        "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)",
        "Module.load (module.js:356:32)",
        "Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)",
        "Module.require (module.js:364:17)"
      ]
    }
```

I've already tried to add in the json config  "request":"*", I re installed the package many times too but it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging based [on this github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10399), you'll want to reinstall Node.js and NPM, clear the node_modules folder and run `npm install` again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i reinstall node and all the node_modules, now it works !

Answer (score 0):

Your version of NodeJS probably differs from what Lambda is currently running.

1. Uninstall NodeJS
2. Delete your node_modules folder
3. Install the correct NodeJS version that you have specified for
   Lambda: [v4.3.2](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v4.3.2/)    (Preferred) or [v0.10.42](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v0.10.42/)
4. run `npm install`